# Call a function from a function in a class

Tags: php, function

I have this php code and i want to call the `function firstnameLength()` from the `class formular_validiation`.

```
class formular_validiation
{
    private static $minLength = 2;
    private static $maxLength = 250;
    public static function firstname() {

        function firstnameLength($firstnameLength){
            if ($firstnameLength < self::$minLength){

            }
            elseif ($firstnameLength > self::$maxLength) {

            }
        }

        function firstnameNoSpace($firstnameNoSpace) {
            preg_replace(" ", "", $firstnameNoSpace);
        }

    }
}
```

I thougth about something like:

```
formular_validiation::firstname()::firstnamelength()
```

but this is wrong.

Comment: use `$this->function_name` for call function in same class

Comment: this won't work 'cause the function is inside a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `method chaining` but if you want to call the first method statically you should do something like:

```
class FormularValidation
{
    private $minLength = 2;
    private $maxLength = 250;
    private $firstname;

    public function __construct($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

    public static function firstname($firstname) {
        return new self($firstname);
    }

    public function firstnameLength()
    {
        $firstnameLength = strlen($this->firstname);

        if ($firstnameLength < $this->minLength){
            return 'something';
        }
        elseif ($firstnameLength > $this->maxLength) {
            return 'something else';
        }
    }

    public function firstnameNoSpace()
    {
         return preg_replace(" ", "", $this->firstname);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$firstnameLength = FormularValidation::firstname('Mihai')->firstnameLength();
```

Comment: thanks for taking that time to correct it :) works awasome